# JQuery <html> class to trigger 3D transforms

Tags: jquery, html, class, css, 3d

I am looking for a nice method to cue css3 3d transforms, by adding classes to the html tag using JQuery.  I have a menu like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="menu1"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="menu2"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li class="menu3"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li class="menu4"><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li class="menu5"><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    <li class="menu6"><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

For example if '.menu1 a' is clicked, I'd like to add the class 'show1' to the html tag.  'show2' if '.menu2 a' is clicked etc.

However for my transitions to work correctly I also need another class to be added, then removed after a set time like 3 seconds.  So if '.menu1 a' is clicked, the html class would be 'show1 zoom' for 3 seconds, then just 'show1'.  And if '.menu2 a' is clicked, the html class would be 'show2 twirl' for example.

I don't mind setting the name of the transition (zoom, twirl, etc.) manually in the script, but if it's easier/neater I could use a system of classes on the li, like 'menu1 p-show1 t-zoom'.

I have a half-working example [here](http://codepen.io/daviestar/pen/tpoJc).  If you inspect the html tag (click gear beside html) and change the html class from 'show1' to 'show2 zoom' you will see the desired transition, which should be the cube rotating to the correct side (.show2) and also a fancy transition (.zoom) on top.  Everything is working correctly except the .js which I can't get working at all!

**New demo [here](http://static.houseofyum.co.uk/cube/).**

Comment: Are you willing to modify your HTML a tad?

Comment: sure, i can work round it :)

Comment: Can I get a list of all the classes? (I'm too lazy to go through the demo css)

Comment: If you mean the 'system of classes' bit I mention above, see these as an example of all classes: 'menu1 p-show1 t-zoom' 'menu2 p-show2 t-spin-light' 'menu3 p-show3 t-stutter' 'menu4 p-show4 t-flatten' 'menu5 p-show5 t-wander' 'menu6 p-show6 t-open'.  P stands for position, which side of the cube is facing front, T stands for transition name.  I can add these to the HTML and they could be picked up by the script and injected into the html tag?

Comment: Ok, and the transitions are the ones that are removed after 3 seconds? It took me a few minutes to figure out how it all worked. Plus the vodka doesn't help. Lol

Answer (score 1):

[**Old CodePen Demo**](http://codepen.io/joe/pen/JlCjH)

P.S. I think those transitions are awesome!

**EDIT:**

Code changes to fix the pre-3second click transition bug:

```
var currentShow, currentTransition, currentTimeout;

$('.menu ul li a').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $li = $this.closest('li');
    var index = $li.attr('class').replace(/menu/, '');
    var $html = $li.closest('html');

    $html.removeClass(currentShow);

    if (currentTransition) {
        $html.removeClass(currentTransition);
        clearTimeout(currentTimeout);
        setTimeout(function () {
            DoTransition(index, $html); 
        },50);
    } else {
        DoTransition(index, $html); 
    }

});

function DoTransition(index, $html) {
    currentShow = 'show'.concat(index);
    currentTransition = GetTransitionString(index);

    $html.addClass(currentShow + ' ' + currentTransition);

    currentTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $html.removeClass(currentTransition);
        currentTransition = null;
    }, 3000);
}

function GetTransitionString(index) {
    var transition;

    switch (parseInt(index)) {
        case 1:
            transition = 'zoom';
            break;
        case 2:
            transition = 'zoom';
            break;
        case 3:
            transition = 'zoom';
            break;
        case 4:
            transition = 'zoom';
            break;
        case 5:
            transition = 'zoom';
            break;
        case 6:
            transition = 'zoom';
            break;
    }

    return transition;
}
```

[**Updated CodePen Demo**](http://codepen.io/zebra/pen/yCeLB)

Comment: i have the demo [here](http://static.houseofyum.co.uk/cube/). it does everything i need it to do, thanks! :) right now there is a bug where clicking the next item within 3 seconds doesn't trigger the 'zoom' transition, but that is my fault as they are currently all set to 'zoom' until i make more transitions.  i have a strange issue- i can't click on sides 3-6, not to do with the js, i think it's to do with the 3d rotation.. any ideas? new question?

Comment: @daviestar thanks for the feedback, I've made some code changes in my answer to fix the pre-3second click transition bug, let me know if it works well for you.

Comment: I updated the demo [here](http://static.houseofyum.co.uk/cube/).  Thanks, this is working perfectly :)  Now I get to have fun making more transitions and backgrounds! Not sure if I should make this my accepted answer as both scripts work well and have pros and cons.  Your solution is more stable in my testing.

Comment: @daviestar I like "Thanks, this is working perfectly :)" - Good luck with the rest of your project.

Comment: @daviestar You should accept the answer that works best (in this case this one).

Comment: @Asad My problems with both scripts could be related to my incomplete CSS.  So I should wait until I can fulfill my own spec before accepting an answer.

Comment: @daviestar What is the issue you're having with my solution? You're able to click all elements without the script breaking & it does not matter whether you click < 3s or more, the transition will run - Please update your question with current issues.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a condensed version:

```
$('.menu ul li a').click(function() {
    var i = $(this).parent('li').index() + 1, 
       mc = $(this).parent('li').attr('class'),
      trg = $(this).closest('html'),
       cc = trg.attr('class'),
       newclass;
       switch (i) {
           case 1: var effect = 'zoom';
               break;
           case 2: var effect = 'spin-light';
               break;
           case 3: var effect = 'stutter';
               break;
           case 4: var effect = 'flatten';
               break;
           case 5: var effect = 'wander';
               break;
           case 6: var effect = 'open';
               break;                               
       }
      newclass = mc+' show'+i+' '+effect+' -webkit-';
      trg.attr('class', newclass).delay(3000).queue(function(){$(this).removeClass(effect);$(this).dequeue();}); 
});
```

I researched for a long time into the CSS animation issue. Only sides 1 and 2 have clickable menus. For some reason the other sides are having issues. Right clicking and inspecting element takes me to the cube wrapper. From the research I've done, I'm guessing it has to do with `::before` and `::after` [More Info](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/css3-animations-the-hiccups-and-bugs-youll-want-to-avoid/)

I hope this all helps.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason it's not working for me - the body class is changing to 'menu2 show2' instead of 'show2 zoom' when clicking on the 2nd menu item.  Should I edit the html?  I'm still stumped on the clicking issue.. I tried :before and :after hacks but no dice.  1 and 2 are front and back sides - meaning they still have x and y of 500px in 2D when the page loads, but the other 4 sides are invisible before the rotation.. my guess is the problem comes from this.

Comment: Are you sure about the classes? It's applied to the `<HTML>` tag just as you asked, 'menu1 show1 zoom' (there's also '-webkit-' used by that other js). And then 3 seconds after it's applied the effect class is removed, in this case 'zoom'. Or did you not want the menu class applied too?

Comment: You can have a look at it [here](http://static.houseofyum.co.uk/cube/cubes4.html).  Apologies if it's a n00b js issue caused by me :)

Comment: The last two lines are the 'meat'. `newclass = mc+' show'+i+' '+effect+' -webkit-';` <- this is what classes get applied, remove `mc+` to take off the menu class. `trg.attr('class', newclass).delay(3000).removeClass(effect); ` <- this is what applies the classes, notice the `delay(3000)`, that waits 3 seconds and then proceeds to remove the effect class (like zoom). No need to apologize, I initially misunderstood. As for the CSS animation, that's not my forte.

Comment: is it working for you? it doesn't apply 'zoom' or other transition names for me :( fixed the clicking bug - added perspective: 5000px; to .cube_wrap.

Comment: Oh I totally forgot about `.delay()` and it's issue with CSS. Here's the fix: `trg.attr('class', newclass).delay(3000).queue(function(){$(this).removeClass(effect);$(this).dequeue();});` I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I have an updated demo [here](http://static.houseofyum.co.uk/cube/index2.html).  It's working now, thanks!  It seems possible to break it though- when I click fairly quickly it sometimes misses the transition name (zoom).  This is possibly to do with them all currently being called 'zoom' and may correct itself when they have different names.  Thanks for all your work.

Comment: I'd recommend changing the timing to less than 3 seconds. Maybe use `1500` rather than `3000`.

Comment: Yeah I plan to experiment with that. If this works the way I hope there may be funky things I can do by mixing the css animation duration and the js html class duration. Cheers.